# Customizing the Image sizes on the home page in a Spree Application

Tags: image, paperclip, product, spree, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Guys How to change the image size for a particular product on the Home page
Like in default images size is small(100 x 100)
I want to increase the image size but how i couldn't get it!!
please Help me out guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by download all the spree views and go to the provided link and give some class of any width and height.

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_products.html.erb

Thanks

Comment: so u mean shall i download that file->
add the class attribute to the image-> copy that file to my app folder??

Comment: yeah with the same hierarchy.

Comment: one more thing Quibaish Bhatti, do we need to copy all the views,models and controllers from the gem file to the app directory and start developing??

Comment: all the views model and controllers or only the particular ones we need to edit?? for the developing purpose

Comment: Not all, only those which you need.

Comment: Thank you very much Qubaish Bhatti